# Wordpress $wpdb->update not working correct in for loop

Tags: sql, wordpress

Wordpress `$wpdb->update()` function is not executing the sql. I tried hard coded the values, it worked but not working in loop.
Here is my code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($excelData); $i++) { 
    $product = $excelData[$i];

    $product_id = $product['item_id'];
    $product_price = $product['item_price'];
    
    // $sqlStrings[] = "UPDATE $branch SET price = $product_price WHERE details_id = $product_id";
    $wpdb->update(
        $branch,
        array(
            'price' => $product_price,
        ),
        array(
            'details_id' => $product_id,
        ),
    );

}
```

Loop is repeating self 140 times.

Comment: Did you use `global $wpdb`?

Comment: yes. i used....